# Injecting browser prefixes for grid not working with Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I've blown an afternoon on this already and I'm stumped. I clock that IE11 doesn't support `grid-template` and that I need to use `-ms-grid-columns` and `-ms-grid-rows` instead but I'm trying to generate some CSS and inject it via a Vue method. This works in every browser except IE11:

```
gridTemplate: function(){
    var gridTemplate = "display: grid;";
    gridTemplate += "grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr ) / repeat(4, 1fr);";
    gridTemplate += "grid-gap: 3px;";
    return gridTemplate;
}
```

So, to try and get it working in IE11 I instead use this behind a conditional to check if it is that browser:

```
gridTemplate: function(){
    var gridTemplate = "display: -ms-grid;";
    gridTemplate += " -ms-grid-columns: " + _.fill(Array(4),"1fr").join(" ") + ";";
    gridTemplate += " -ms-grid-rows: " + _.fill(Array(4),"1fr").join(" ") + ";";
    gridTemplate += "grid-gap: 3px;";
    return gridTemplate;
}
```

As you can tell no doubt tell, I'm using lodash and when I console log the result before returning the CSS I get this: `display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-gap: 3px;`, but when I inspect the element in IE11 all I get through is: `<div style="display: -ms-grid;">` and the `-ms-grid-columns` and `-ms-grid-rows` are ignored. I've tried and used the lodash `_.fill` in other browsers and it works a treat, so I'm pretty sure it's not that. I need the number of rows and columns to be dynamic you see, which is why I'm not just writing it in auto-prefixed SCSS.

I'm sort of wondering if this is down to something with Vue and if so does anyone have any ideas about how to rectify it... hey, if it isn't a Vue thing can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using vue-cli and/or webpack?

Comment: What are you doing with the result of `gridTemplate`? Binding it to the style?

Comment: @zero298, no vue-cli or webpack, just vanilla Vue included in the head.

Comment: @Bert, just so. So: `<div v-bind:style="gridTemplate()"></div>`.

Comment: Is there anything dynamic about the columns/rows? Right now it looks hard coded. If it's hardcoded, I would probably just bind a class. You'll have some issues with those prefixes in typical binding situations.

Comment: @Bert, I know it looks as though they're hardcoded but that 4 can go up and down... I did ponder writing specific SCSS because it's a limited scale between 3 and 7, I guess that's what I'll end up doing if you can't think of anything else? :-(

Comment: Perhaps someone will chime in with a better idea, but I can't even get that string to bind properly in Chrome. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XBWqJy?editors=1010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174739/discussion-between-annoyingmouse-and-bert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you shouldn't actually include the vendor prefixes and that Vue will add them automatically.  See documentation: [Auto-prefixing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Auto-prefixing).

Consider this screen shot of the IE11 browser tools running the code below:

[image: IE11 Developer tools of code below]

```js
const foo = {
  methods: {
    gridTemplate: function() {
      return {
        "display": "-ms-grid",
        "grid-columns": _.fill(Array(4), "1fr").join(" "),
        "grid-rows": _.fill(Array(4), "1fr").join(" "),
        "grid-gap": "3px"
      }
    }
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    foo: foo
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <foo inline-template>
    <div :style="gridTemplate()"></div>
  </foo>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Always trust Vue eh? :-)

Comment: @annoyingmouse Well, I figured it had to be doing some magic with the prefixes.  I had run into an issue with the webpack style loader for gradients before but since you aren't using webpack, I thought it wasn't related.  Glad it's fixed though.

Comment: @zero298 Will this work the same for other grid properties like grid-column-start, grid-row-start. I am asking because those properties does not have keyword "start" in IE 11, it's just "-ms-grid-row" and "-ms-grid-column".

Comment: @romie99 I'm not sure, I would expect it to add it automatically and basically add whatever rule needed to be there.  It looks like IE11 uses an older spec version of CSS Grid so the correct rule would probably be applied but overloaded similar to how other vendor prefixes work.  I'd say try it and check, I don't have IE11 to test with.