# How Vue knows which prefix should prepend when different browser?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-4

Like

```html
<template>
  <h1 :style={ filter: 'blur(1px)' }>My Template!!</h1>
</template>
```

I used `style` and `webkit` to search source code from `node_modules/Vue` and `node_modules/@Vue`, but had no luck.

How Vue knows which prefix should prepend when different browser?? So magic it is!!

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Auto-prefixing

Comment: [Example: injecting-browser-prefixes-for-grid-not-working-with-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268572/injecting-browser-prefixes-for-grid-not-working-with-vue)

Comment: They use [PostCSS & autoprefixer](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#postcss)

Comment: @StevenB. the size of Vue is 63.5kb, the PostCss 70.6kb even the autoprefixer is 769kb. I knew PostCss and Autoprefixer will precompile CSS, but the inline style could be dynamic, how Vue knows? could u show any source code from Vue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I found the answer.
The code is under `vue/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/style.js` line 32

```js
const vendorNames = ['Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms']

let emptyStyle
const normalize = cached(function (prop) {
  emptyStyle = emptyStyle || document.createElement('div').style
  prop = camelize(prop)
  if (prop !== 'filter' && (prop in emptyStyle)) {
    return prop
  }
  const capName = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1)
  for (let i = 0; i < vendorNames.length; i++) {
    const name = vendorNames[i] + capName
    if (name in emptyStyle) {
      return name
    }
  }
})
```

The `emptyStyle` here is `CSSStyleDeclaration` from browser.
Vue will check every attribute with prefix in CSSStyleDeclaration or not. 
If yes then will append it and cache it.
However, it looks like the `filter` attribute is an exception here.

Most of CSS we will write in CSS file then it will be compiled by PostCSS and Autoprefixer. Consider the runtime, the code above I guess is the easiest and smallest way to achieve, yet still have some surprises.